# RazorTemplateEngine parser produces unusual syntax tree

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I was looking for a way to to reuse my MVC Razor views as javascript templates for client side rendering, and found [this library](https://github.com/jchadwick/RazorClientTemplates) (Razor Client Template) which parses razor views into javascript functions.

It doesn't play ball with Razor engine version 2, and a little digging shows this is because the Razor engine's syntax tree has been overhauled. In an attempt to modify things, I've found some weird results from the RazorViewEngine parser.

I have a very simple view, like so:

```
@model Justis4.Models.EntityModel
<div>
    @Model.PropertyOne
    @Model.PropertyTwo
</div>
```

The razor client template library starts off with:

```
var host = new RazorEngineHost(newCSharpRazorCodeLanguage());
var engine = new RazorTemplateEngine(host);
var parserResults = engine.ParseTemplate(razorTemplate);  //from string reader
var doc = parserResults.Document;
```

and then goes off to start parsing the resulting syntax tree into a javascript function.

When I debug through the syntax tree, I see some odd stuff. As I understand it, the Razor engine splits the view into "blocks" and "spans" of different types. But as in the picture, the model declaration at the top has been parsed as markup, not code. There are similar oddities, and as a result, the rest of the parsing to javascript fails.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The standard razor parser does not recognise the `@model` keyword. The `@model` keyword comes from the [MvcCSharpRazorCodeParser](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8b6e0c95ffc6#src/System.Web.Mvc/Razor/MvcCSharpRazorCodeParser.cs) class in the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly.

The main functionality for this comes from [SetModelTypeCodeGenerator](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8b6e0c95ffc6#src/System.Web.Mvc/Razor/SetModelTypeCodeGenerator.cs). This class makes use of the core razor engine class, [SetBaseTypeCodeGenerator](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8b6e0c95ffc6#src/System.Web.Razor/Generator/SetBaseTypeCodeGenerator.cs) to change the base type for the razor view from the default `WebViewPage` to `WebViewPage<Model>`.

## Solutions

Use the `@inherits` keyword instead e.g. `@inherits WebViewPage<EntityModel>`.

Or, add a reference to `System.Web.Mvc` and use a custom language change the code parser to `MvcCSharpRazorCodeParser`. You will need to set the `RazorEngine.DefaultBaseClass` property to a non-generic version of the base class you intend to use, e.g. for `WebViewPage<T>` you would set `engine.DefaultBaseClass = "System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage"`.

```
class MvcCSharpRazorCodeLanguage : CSharpRazorCodeLanguage
{
    public override ParserBase CreateCodeParser()
    {
        return new MvcCSharpRazorCodeParser();
    }
}
```